# Qt, Linker error: can not find IGL

Tags: c++, c, qt, ubuntu, linker

When I try to compile the HelloWorld widget application in Qt, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

I searched in the Internet but could not find what is the name of the package that contains this library.
I use ubuntu and have essential build tools installed on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

basically you should look for libGL (libGL.so). But the package to install depends on your graphics card

For nvida it is `nvidia-331-updates` (newer or older ones will also work)